# Возвращение значения

Tags: c++

Мне нужно, чтобы в случае неверного ввода password запрашивало password до тех пор пока не будет password верен

```
int main()
{
    setlocale(0, "");
    system("title DECIDED SERVER GUARD");
    string user_pass; //Пароль который будет вводить пользыватель
    string valid_pass = "sh0rtenconst"; //Пароль доступа
        cout << "Введите пароль: "; //Ввод проля
        cin >> user_pass;
    if (user_pass == valid_pass) {
        ofstream fout;
        fout.open("decidedserver.txt");
        fout << "SPEEEEEEERMRAZORJKEE2h1gw0w/A/";
        fout.close();
    }
    else {
        cout << "Пароль не принят" << endl;
    }
    _getch();
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1):

Задача решается циклом с предусловием и использованием флаговой переменной.

```
int main()
{
    setlocale(0, "");
    system("title DECIDED SERVER GUARD");
    string user_pass; //Пароль который будет вводить пользыватель
    string valid_pass = "sh0rtenconst"; //Пароль доступа
    cout << "Введите пароль: "; //Ввод пароля

    bool isCorrectPassword = false;
    while(!isCorrectPassword)
    {
        cin >> user_pass;
        isCorrectPassword = user_pass == valid_pass;
        if(!isCorrectPassword)
            cout << "Пароль не принят" << endl;
    }

    ofstream fout;
    fout.open("decidedserver.txt");
    fout << "SPEEEEEEERMRAZORJKEE2h1gw0w/A/";
    fout.close();

    _getch();
    return 0;
}
```